# how to get position of robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can anybody tell me how to get the robot position(odometry x and y ) from tf message in c++ file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56235/how-to-get-position-of-robot./) by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) defines this.

You are looking for the transform /odom -> /base_link.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0